# Unable to view published web service from mobile first

Tags: java, spring, web-services, ibm-mobilefirst, jax-ws

I have a Mobile First project and inside has a web service. When I published it and entering http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/adapters/abcMfpApi/test into browser, I cannot view the published web service and showing HTTP 404 Not Found error.

Below is the applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
    xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
         http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

    <wss:binding url="/test">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#testWS" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <bean id="testWS" class="abc.controller.CallbackControllerTest" />

</beans>
```

Below is the web service class:

```
package abc.controller;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

    @WebService(endpointInterface = "abc.controller.callbackControllerInterface")
    public class CallbackControllerTest implements CallbackControllerInterface {

        @Override
        public void Notify(String event) {

        }
    }
```

Below is the interface class:

```
package abc.controller;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface CallbackControllerInterface {

    @WebMethod
    public void Notify(String event);
}
```

Below is the error log from Mobile First:

```
2019-04-25 17:17:03.688 [UnknownExceptionMapper] - Exception detected
javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:117) ~[SpecExceptions.class:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:162) ~[ExceptionUtils.class:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:528) ~[JAXRSUtils.class:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:177) ~[JAXRSInInterceptor.class:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77) ~[JAXRSInInterceptor.class:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[PhaseInterceptorChain.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[ChainInitiationObserver.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251) ~[AbstractHTTPDestination.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[ServletController.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[ServletController.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[ServletController.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171) ~[CXFNonSpringServlet.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293) ~[AbstractHTTPServlet.class:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) ~[AbstractHTTPServlet.class:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268) ~[AbstractHTTPServlet.class:3.1.0]
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox$3.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:579) ~[mfp-server.war:?]
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86) ~[mfp-server.war:?]
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:584) ~[mfp-server.war:?]
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.rest.AdaptersEndpoint.adapterServing(AdaptersEndpoint.java:123) ~[mfp-server.war:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[InvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[InvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) ~[RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[DispatcherServlet.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[DispatcherServlet.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.11.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1158) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:928) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929) ~[?:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
[INFO ]    2019-04-25 17:17:03.692 [InboundBodyLogger] - inbound-response|Method:GET|Endpoint:/mfp/api/adapters/abcMfpApi/test|Header:{Content-Type=[application/json], Date=[Thu, 25 Apr 2019 09:17:03 GMT]}|Body:{"errorCode":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","errorMessage":"Internal server error"}
```

Anyone could help on my questions as follows?

1. How to know the exact url of the published web service?
2. If my http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/adapters/abcMfpApi/test url is
   correct, why mobile first returning me 404 error?

Comment: Did you create a MFP adapter 'abcMfpApi' and write code within it, to invoke the said Webservice?

Comment: Hi, Vivin. Yes. I have that adapter created. abcMfpApi is just a masking name i use here due to not able to disclose the actual name. But the adapter is created

Comment: The 404 in the stacktrace indicates the URL to the backend ( in the adapter code) is wrong. In Java adapters, the code to invoke the backend should be added by the developer. Verify if this is correct. If you were to invoke another simple RESTful backend, do you see a response? Pass on the adapter code for verification.